# Animation error with Kivy Python?

Tags: python, animation, kivy

I'm trying to animate an app . It shows an error code that says build needs two arguments(1 given). Here is my code:

```
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.image import Image 
from kivy.animation import Animation 

class TheApp(App): 

    def build(self, instance):
        self.instance= instance
        image = Image(source= "psychTREE.jpg")
        image.allow_stretch= True

        animation = Animation(pos= (100, 100), t= "out_bounce") 
        animation += Animation(pos= (200, 100), t = "out_bounce") 
        animation &= Animation(size= (500, 500))
        animation += Animation(size= (100, 50)) 

        image = animation.start(instance)  
        return image 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TheApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `build` method doesn't receive any arguments other than the (automatic) self; the error means it expects a second argument that you called `instance`, but doesn't receive it.

Comment: But I thought I already added a second argument in the build(self, instance). I further initialized it with self.instance= instance. So I don't quite get what you are saying? how should I fix this?

Comment: You defined a function that *takes* a second argument, but when the function is actually called by kivy it is not *given* a second argument, therefore it fails. I'm not sure what you expect instance to actually be.

Comment: I get what you're saying, but I don't know how to give the second argument, can you please post a code snippet to give some further understanding?

Comment: I can't post a code snippet because I don't understand what you're trying to do. What exactly do you want/expect `instance` to be?

Comment: I want instance to be correlated with image so that animation shows the image moving from frame to frame. Here is the example instance in kivy: https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/examples/animation/animate.py